# question on flink's error on connecting to remote task manager

Tags: apache-flink

My flink version is 1.8.0.

I have losts of errors like below last night.
Error Message:

> - Sink: Unnamed (11/40) (71881eb39a89b2984989154a2aa24709) switched from RUNNING to FAILED.
>
> java.io.IOException: Connecting the channel failed: Connecting to
>   remote task manager + 'dn5/ip:port' has
>   failed. This might indicate that the remote task manager has been
>   lost.

I can always find this error in my flink program, this error will fail my subtask and restart the whole job.(maybe only restart the failed subtask in flink 1.9)

My question is `What cause this kind of error`, it's just some problem in network connection and I can ignore it?

Comment: Sounds like some of your taskmanagers failed? Could be any reason: Network, Memory issues ... Where does your cluster run? Bare metal? Kubernetes? Yarn?

Comment: Suggest you look in the task manager log for clues.

Comment: @TobiSH on yarn

Comment: @DavidAnderson Encountered error while consuming partitions java.io.IOException: Connection timed out

Comment: @DavidAnderson Buffer pool is Destoried  I encountered these two errors in tm.

Comment: @jayWong - did you check the application logs of the task manager (you can find them in the attempts of your yarn application which runs the flink cluster - an indicator is already if you find an attempt where the suffix (_00001, _00002) is somehow "out of order" (e.g. you have 4 task manager + 1 job manager but one attempt has a suffix of _00006 but no one with a _00002 suffix).

Comment: @TobiSH I didn't have an eye on it. And the log had already gone. What it means if the out-of-order suffix exists?

Comment: That basically means that a Taskmanager failed and had to be restarted. Can you reproduce this behaviour?

Comment: @TobiSH I will keep an eye on it.